# Error: "bad variable type" in CComVariant::Copy when iterating through CComSafeArray

Tags: c++, visual-c++, com, atl, safearray

```
CComSafeArray<VARIANT> fields;
hr = _tab_file->get_Fields(fields.GetSafeArrayPtr());

for ( LONG i = fields.GetLowerBound(), ie = fields.GetUpperBound(); i <= ie; ++i)
{
    CComVariant fld = fields.GetAt(i); // (1) raises DISP_E_BADVARTYPE (0x80020008L)

    // Next code works fine                
    CComQIPtr<ITabField> field = fields.GetAt(i).punkVal; // (2) Ok
    _bstr_t fieldName;
    hr = field->get_Name(fieldName.GetAddress());
    ::OutputDebugString(fieldName + _T("\n")); // Ok
}
```

Line (1): `fields.GetAt(i)` returns `CComVariant`. When I try to assign this value to `CComVariant fld` called copy constructor and method `CComVariant::Copy` inside the copy constructor. It raise an exception ("bad variable type", `DISP_E_BADVARTYPE (0x80020008L)`).
At the same time the line (2) works well. What's wrong with line (1), and how to fix it.

**EDIT:** This is code for `get_Field` (filling `SAFEARRAY`).

```
STDMETHODIMP TabFile::get_Fields( SAFEARRAY** fields )
{
  if(mapInfoFile_ == 0)
    return E_UNEXPECTED;
  int fieldCount = getFieldCount();
  SAFEARRAY* arr = ::SafeArrayCreateVector(VT_UNKNOWN, 0, fieldCount);
  for(LONG i = 0; i < fieldCount; i++)
  {
    QField* field = getQField(i);
    ITabField* tabField = TabField::CreateInstance();
    tabField->put_Name(_bstr_t(field->GetNameRef()));
    tabField->put_Type(field->GetNativeFieldType(i));
    ::SafeArrayPutElement(arr, &i, tabField);
    tabField->Release();
  }
  *fields = arr;
  return S_OK;
}
```

Comment: `GetAt(i)` will get you `CComVariant&` type. So you can update your `fld` variable to be a reference type and check what you have there and why exactly the thing does not go through assignment/duplication.

Comment: @RomanR. Ok, I rewrote (1) like this `CComVariant &fld = fields.GetAt(i);`. Works fine, but I don't know how to understand now, what is the problem with the copy constructor

Comment: Now you have the `fld` variable and you can inspect it. Check if its `.vt` is good and is not junk. After all, this value is not valid for copy, so there should be something wrong with it and you should be able to see it with debugger.

Comment: @RomanR. Thank you. I expanded question. `vt` looks good. Line (2) works well. And I can get value (`fieldName`, for example) and print it out.

Comment: Looks like you got it to work, but out of curiousity what is `.vt` exactly there?

Comment: @RomanR. `vt = 0xdf18` However, the question still isn't clear. What is the problem with ComVariant::Copy?

Comment: `.vt` is exactly the problem. Your variant is `.vt` + `.punkVal`. `.punkVal` seems to be valid, but `.vt` has to be something like `VT_UNKNOWN` or `VT_DISPATCH` in order for API to realize you have an interface there. You seems to have junk so API fails. This is the reason and you eventually hit the cause.

Comment: @RomanR. Thanks. So, maybe I incorrectly filled SAVEARRAY. I'll add code now.

Comment: You create an array of `IUnknown`s and then you are trying to interpret is as array of `VARIANT`. Those should be the same types, you want either array of unknowns and you pack interface into CComVariant before putting it into array in the getter, or otherwise caller will deal with array of interfaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You create an array of `IUnknown`s and then you are trying to interpret
>   is as array of `VARIANT`. Those should be the same types, you want
>   either array of unknowns and you pack interface into `CComVariant`
>   before putting it into array in the getter, or otherwise caller will
>   deal with array of interfaces.

As you discovered a mismatch between actual array element type and the type you are casting it to, you will need to update your getter implementation and caller code to match one another.

My personal preference is to create an array of variants, `VT_ARRAY | VT_VARIANT` and put the array into `[out] VARIANT*` argument. The caller would unwind it back from variant to array, check array type, and then obtain the elements. This is a minimal overhead, and the code around `VARIANT` type is best - on the average - in terms of interoperability (in your particular case you definitely might be good with raw types, and without variants at all).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are having the typical off-by-one error. `ie` is one element past the last one, so `fields.GetAt(i)` when `i == ie` will return you a non-existent element. Try replacing `i <= ie` with `i < ie` in the `for` loop termination condition and see if it works.

Even though the `CComVariant` copy constructor fails for `i == ie`, the next assignment might seem to work because the `CComQIPtr<ITabField>` copy constructor may be happy with whatever is retrieved at the `punkVal` field of the spurious `CComVariant`.

Comment: Safe array bounds are inclusive on both ends, that is `GetAt(GetUpperBound())` is OK.